# Image follow cursor or rotate as it moves

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

im trying to find a way to make an image move or follow the mouse cursor.
Basically i have a radial pie menu and i'd like the image thats in the middle of it, to spin and rotate as the mouse mouves.

Any ideias how i can do that?

Appreciate the help!!!

Comment: There are some solutions that you could use for your project.
https://github.com/axln/radial-menu-js here is an example that you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first what you can do is make the image or the element that you want to follow the cursor to absolute position

```
#image {
position:absolute;
}
```

then, you can set left and top poosition of the image that equal to cursor position with mousemove event
example with jquery

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```

or you can do it just with vanilla JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  let body = document.querySelector('body');
  let image = document.getElementById('image');
  let left = e.offsetX;
  let top = e.offsetY;
  image.style.left = left + 'px';
  image.style.top = top + 'px';
});
```

Hopefully my answer can help you.